# Error when traversing through the panda dataframe to generate boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boxplot

I want to generate a boxplot for each attribute in the df panda dataframe.

When I try the below code,

```
features = df.columns
#print(features)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=[features[1]])
temp_df.boxplot()
```

the boxplot for the first feature is generated successfully but from the second feature, it gives me the below error.

```
usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, backend, **kwargs)
    503         layout=layout,
    504         return_type=return_type,
--> 505         **kwargs,
    506     )
    507 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in boxplot_frame(self, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    389         layout=layout,
    390         return_type=return_type,
--> 391         **kwds,
    392     )
    393     plt.draw_if_interactive()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in boxplot(data, column, by, ax, fontsize, rot, grid, figsize, layout, return_type, **kwds)
    357             data = data[columns]
    358 
--> 359         result = plot_group(columns, data.values.T, ax)
    360         ax.grid(grid)
    361 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/boxplot.py in plot_group(keys, values, ax)
    302             ticks = ax.get_xticks()
    303             if len(ticks) != len(keys):
--> 304                 i, remainder = divmod(len(ticks), len(keys))
    305                 assert remainder == 0, remainder
    306                 keys *= i

ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

Can help on this is highly appreciated!!

Comment: We cannot reproduce the issue without a sample of data that is causing the problem, thus it will be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

`boxplot`, like most pandas plotting functions, need numeric data. Furthermore, the data must be specified in the DataFrame as a numeric type.

Is your `df3[features[1]]` set as object type? I ran into exactly this issue just now, and realizing the data was marked as object and forcing the datatype fixed the issue.

Try `temp_df = pd.DataFrame(df3, columns=[features[1]], dtype='float')`, or whatever numeric dtype makes sense for you.